# Unsure if have user query correct for ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to convert my old user query `select*from` to the new codeigniter way but I am not sure if I have it correct.

This is my old way

```
$user_query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user WHERE username = '" .
        $this->db->escape($username) . 
        "' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" .
        $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))) OR password = '" . 
        $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "') AND status = '1'"
    );
```

And this is new way. I am unsure if have `select * from` correct I have removed the messy salt and `SHA1`.

```
public function login() {
        $this->db->select('user');

        $this->db->from('user_id');

        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));

        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        // Password Has Own Security Measures
        $this->db->where('password',  $this->encryption->hash_password().hash('sha512', $password).$this->encryption->generate_salt());

        $this->db->where('status', "1");

        $user_query = $this->db->get('user');

        if($user_query->num_rows) {

        } else {
            /*
            | Other Data Goes Here.
            |
            |
             **/
            return true;
        }
      return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain your DB in CodeIgniter, and you had some errors in your from :

```
$password = $this->input->post('password');

$query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->where('username', $this->input->post('username'))
            ->where('password',  $this->encryption->hash_password().hash('sha512', $password).$this->encryption->generate_salt())
            ->where('status', "1")
            ->get('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

you're confusing the [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) functions, you can chain it, like, do:

```
....
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$username = $this->input->post('username');

$user_query = $this->db->select('user_id')    
->where( 
    array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $this->encryption->hash_password().hash('sha512', $password).$this->encryption->generate_salt(),
        'status'   => 1
    )
)
->get('user');
.....
```